# Reversing a substring

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
myname = "John Malkovich"
```

I would like to have part of it reversed. I would like to get:

```
"John voklaMich"
```

If I write:

```
myname[4..10].reverse
```

that only gives that part of string. The result is:

```
"voklaM"
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets break your expression apart:

```
myname[4..10].reverse
```

is roughly like saying

```
temp = myname[4..10]
temp.reverse
```

you want to do something like this

```
myname[4..10] = myname[4..10].reverse
```

Comment: Now I fully get it, thanks for great answer. appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
myname[5..10] = myname[5..10].reverse
```

Comment: That's it, it was a total newbie question, but thank you for answering. Cheers! :)